# ios scrolling over a large uiview memory problems

Tags: ios, memory, uiview, scrollview

I'm making a music app that displays musical notation. Currently the notation is in a very large view that extends horizontally until the music ends. Obviously this isn't a good solution because I quickly run out of memory when display large scores of music.

My question is how I can implement my view such that the view where I do my drawing is only the size of the screen, but the content gets scrolled across it (The view is contained in a scrollview)? I imagine I could just only draw stuff on the screen and redraw the view as it gets scrolled with different x coordinates, but this seems ugly and would be pretty slow.

Thanks for any suggestions. : )

Comment: Have you tried to scroll it automatically with `setContentOffset` as the notation is drawn ? Together with `setScrollEnabled` it might give you a fast solution.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, looking at setContentOffset, it will just scroll the scrollview to a particular offset. If the contained view is only the size of the screen, this will do nothing. What I need is to offset the content in my notation view (the one that performs the drawing).

Comment: That was assuming you'll want to keep the content view size increasing but make the user do not know about it. If you want to get rid of the scroll view, the best solution would be to make the drawing at `drawRect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of solutions around. Usually these involve drawing one-or-two screen widths past the edges, then scrolling as needed, and drawing again into the area that was previously visible. In essence, using the scroll-view as a circular buffer.

Try a Google search for [UIScrollView infinite scroll](http://www.google.com/search?q=uiscrollview%20infinite%20scroll).

Also, see [Infinite horizontal scrolling UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440230/infinite-horizontal-scrolling-uiscrollview).

Comment: So, to check if I'm understanding the suggestions in the links properly: I have a view which is larger than the screen contained in a scrollview. When scrolled, the scrollview will go as far as possible, and when it reaches the end of the big view, it tells the view to redraw with the next part couple screenfulls of data and snaps the scroll back to the beginning. Correct?

Comment: Yep, that's the general idea. In the interests of full disclosure, I should note that I've never actually implemented one of these, but I've considered their use, several times :-)